# ASP.NET Core track active Page for sidebar using ViewComponent

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core

this is the default view for my sidebar view component

```
                <li class="nav-header text-center pb-1 text-white"><strong>Menu de Navegação</strong></li>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">

                        <a href="@item.Url" class="nav-link custom-sidebar-link">
                            @Html.Raw(@item.Icon)
                            <p class="text-white">
                                @item.Nome
                                @if (item.SubItems != null)
                                {
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        @if (item.SubItems != null)
                        {
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                @foreach (var subItem in item.SubItems)
                                {
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="@subItem.Url" class="nav-link">
                                            @Html.Raw(@subItem.Icon)
                                            <p>
                                                @subItem.Nome
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

and this is the cs file

```
public class SidebarAdminViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var claims = Request.HttpContext.User.Claims;
        var role = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value; ;


        var Sidebar = new SidebarViewModel();

        Sidebar.Items = new List<SidebarItemViewModel>();

        Sidebar.Items.Add(new SidebarItemViewModel
        {
            Nome = "Home",
            Icon = "<i class='nav-icon fas fa-house'></i>",
            Url = Url.Page("/Account/Home/Index")
        });

        Sidebar.Items.Add(sidebarItem);



        return View(Sidebar);
    }
}
```

as can you see there i don't have anything in my code to set an active class. Well that's cause i have that handled right now with javascript

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location;

    // Adds active on inner anchor and treeview anchor and treeview menu-open state to li
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active').parent().parent().siblings().addClass('active').parent().addClass('menu-open');

});
```

I would like to be able to do this just using C# but i have no idea how can i detect the current page the user is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you would do is to get the current page name from the view and add a comparison inside the loop you have (all inside the view)

```
                <li class="nav-header text-center pb-1 text-white"><strong>Menu de Navegação</strong></li>

                @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    @* here for the parent menu item*@
                    <li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower() == item.Name.ToLower() ? "nav-item has-treeview active" : "nav-item has-treeview">

                        <a href="@item.Url" class="nav-link custom-sidebar-link">
                            @Html.Raw(@item.Icon)
                            <p class="text-white">
                                @item.Nome
                                @if (item.SubItems != null)
                                {
                                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        @if (item.SubItems != null)
                        {
                            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                                @foreach (var subItem in item.SubItems)
                                {
                                    @* here for the child menu item*@
                                    <li class=@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower() == item.Url.Split('/').Last().ToLower() ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item">
                                        <a href="@subItem.Url" class="nav-link">
                                            @Html.Raw(@subItem.Icon)
                                            <p>
                                                @subItem.Nome
                                            </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I've used `.ToString().ToLower()` because I was testing before posting, you might not need them